# MSACCESS.EXE does not close when using POP-UP forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Others have had issues with the MSACCESS.EXE process not closing (from Task Manager) when exiting their databases. Each of the posts I've read have had something to do with not properly closing recordset variables.

When I exit the database I'm working on, I notice the MSACCESS.EXE process moves from the "Apps" section to "Background Processes" in Win 10 Task Manager. This hung process continues to utilize RAM. I'm certain that I'm closing all recordset variables properly.

Through a lot of debugging, I figured out a simple way to replicate the problem:

1. Create two forms in a new Access database. Set the PopUp property to True for one of them and False for the other. Save the forms "PopUp" and "NoPopUp" and close the database.
2. Open Task Manager to view the processes running on your screen.
3. Open your Access database and open the NoPopUp form. Note the MSACCESS.EXE process under Apps.
4. Close your database. Note that MSACCESS.EXE is removed from your list of Processes (both under "Apps" and "Background Processes").
5. Now reopen your Access database and open form PopUp. Then close the database.
6. Note that the MSACCESS.EXE process moves from the "Apps" section to "Background Processes" and is still utilizing system memory.

Additional MSACCESS.EXE processes hang in Task Manager each time the database is closed after opening a form with its Pop-up property set to True.

My database uses a ton of Pop-up forms. How should I be closing my database so that these hung processes aren't stacking up? (I'm using Access 2013 in Windows 10.)

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Are the pop-ups forms modals as well?

Comment: Have you tried, explicitly closing the form prior to calling application.close? This may be a garbage collection issue .. may be appropriate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688255/reproduce-msaccess-exe-process-still-running-after-application-exit

Comment: What version of Access? I don't see this behaviour with 2010.

Comment: "(I'm using Access 2013 in Windows 10.)"

Comment: Tested above with both 2010, and 2013 – again not seeing this behaviour.

Comment: @random_answer_guy, sorry I just now saw your reply. Thanks for helping. These pop-up forms are not modal forms and I have tried explicitly closing the form before calling application.quit. I can't recreate this issue on any other machines. It seems to be specific to my computer only! I guess that's better than this problem affecting all of my users.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, sorry I just saw your reply. Thanks for your help. This issue seems to be specific to my computer only.

Answer (score 0):

How are you closing your database now?

Can you change the command to call a function.
Then in that function call a routine that closes all open forms
You may have to add parameter to close without saving - depending on your results.

```
Function CloseAllOpenFrms()
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim DbF                   As Access.Form
    Dim DbO                   As Object

    Set DbO = Application.Forms    'Collection of all the open forms

    For Each DbF In DbO    'Loop all the forms
            DoCmd.Close acForm, DbF.Name, acSaveNo
    Next DbF

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set DbF = Nothing
    Set DbO = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: CloseAllOpenFrms" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description, _
           vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

From http://www.devhut.net/2015/02/17/ms-access-vba-close-all-open-forms/

Comment: Using the steps above to reproduce the problem I'm simply closing the database by clicking the x in the top-right corner. In my actual application I'm using Application.Quit (from a command button).

Your CloseAllOpenFrms function does the job of closing the forms, but the MSACCESS.EXE process still remains once the database is closed (either by clicking the x or using Application.Quit).

Comment: Not clear as to how you're trying to implement it. You can't just put the function in modules and expect it to run itself. Can you show you're code that calls Application.Quit?. One way to make sure you have it implemented for both scenarios is probably to call the function from a hidden form - in the Form unload event. Unload that form from your exit button - get that scenario working first - then we can look at the X button - maybe by using a global var to track where close event called from.

Comment: Hey Mitch. This appears to be an issue only on my computer. I can't recreate this on other machines. 

However, I can repeat the behavior every time on my machine using a new database with a simple popup form without any controls or VBA code. All I have to do is open the form and close the database (without any code) and the MSACCESS.EXE process is moved from "Apps" to "Background Processes" every time. Maybe some sort of memory leak?

Comment: Is everybody else using Windows 10 - is everybody on 64 bit systems?

Comment: That's right, 64 bit Win 10 systems all around w/32 bit Access 2013.

Comment: It does sound like a Windows 10 setting that's different from your users. I'm not that familiar with the O/S, but I have heard about background running processes - mostly Skype, Mail, etc - when you're viewing the app in Background can you check Settings | Permissions and see if `Allow this app to run in background` is turned on?

Comment: Mitch, are you referring to Windows 10 Settings | Privacy | Background Apps which is accessed by the Windows key - I? If so, this only allows turning on and off built-in Win10 apps to run in the background. There's nothing specific to Access here. Or am I in the wrong place? 

Also, let's not lose sight of the fact that if I open non pop-up forms in Access, the MSACCESS.EXE process will not hang. If an "allow apps to run in the background" setting is true, shouldn't I see consistency in the process hanging regardless of whether or not the form is a pop-up form?

Comment: That is a good point. I think I asked before - but still don't see it. Can you update your question to show code that you're using now to close all forms - and from where? Have you confirmed that the CloseAllForms is running when you exit - have your tried adding a debug line`Msgbox "Closing : " & DbF.Name` inside the frm loop? Also - add a DoEvents right afterwards. We're all just guessing as to what code is running on exit right now

Comment: The sample database I put together to replicate this issue uses NO CODE at all. The database contains two forms without any controls. The Pop-up property is true for one form and false for the other. If I open the pop-up form and then close the database by clicking the x in the top-right corner the process hangs in "Background Apps." Every time. This is not the case if I open the non pop-up form and close the database. To clarify, there is ZERO VBA code in this example. I just open the form and close the database.

Comment: Okay - well that doesn't seem to be trying to fix the problem - it does identify the issue, but that was apparent from the start.I thought you were going to add code to close all open forms and test that?

Comment: Okay, so working with code: 
1. I added CloseAllOpenFrms() to a module and added a command button to the PopUp form. The command button calls CloseAllOpenFrms(). Same issue. Here's my code calling your function which is placed in a module:

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    CloseAllOpenFrms
End Sub

Comment: 2. I created a new form and am calling CloseAllOpenFrms from the Unload event of that form. When I close the database the MsgBox shows me that the proper form is about to close. Then I receive error 2501, the close action was canceled.

Comment: You have a new form AND a popup form? I don;t understand. Do you have a sample database? I'd put the code in your Form Unload event .

Comment: I tried calling CloseAllOpenFrms from 1.) The Click event of a command button on a pop-up form and 2.) From the Form_Unload event of another pop-up form. I get the same results from both: Error 2501 - The Close Action was Canceled and an orphaned MSACCESS.EXE process.

I'd be happy to email or upload my sample database if you'd like to see it. Thanks again for sticking with me.

Comment: Sure - send me dropbox url. I'd like it to simulate your real world app as close as possible. So calling unloadall from popup is probably not realistic - mind you I don't have Access 2013 or Windows 10. Maybe I can send you a sample test db instead and you can convert it to 2013.

Comment: You don't have popup form set to modal too do you?

Comment: Modal=False.

Here's a link to the sample database: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mpbrncr7v217h1y/Database1.accdb?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Try this very basic example in a new sample database.

**EDIT:** Add a `Sleep` and `DoEvents` after every close form in case of caching/fast cpu getting ahead of code? Last attempt to fix weird issue.

> In Module 1

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)     

Function CloseAllOpenFrms()

        On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        Dim DbF                   As Access.Form
        Dim DbO                   As Object

        Set DbO = Application.Forms    'Collection of all the open forms

        ' Close all popups first
        For Each DbF In DbO    'Loop all the forms
            If DbF.PopUp Then
                DoCmd.Close acForm, DbF.Name, acSaveNo
                DoEvents
                Sleep 1000
            End If
        Next DbF

        ' Close remaining forms
        For Each DbF In DbO    'Loop all the forms
            DoCmd.Close acForm, DbF.Name, acSaveNo
            DoEvents
            Sleep 1000
        Next DbF

        Application.Quit acQuitSaveNone

    Error_Handler_Exit:
        On Error Resume Next
        Set DbF = Nothing
        Set DbO = Nothing
        Exit Function

    Error_Handler:
        MsgBox "Error closing : " & DbF.Name & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Description: " & Err.Description, _
               vbCritical, "Error closing form"
        Resume Error_Handler_Exit
    End Function
```

> Create basic `Form1` with two command buttons: 
>   Command button `Command1` (Caption= Open Popup Form)
>   Command button `Command0` (Caption = Exit DB)

In Form1's form module paste text

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Command1_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Command1_Click()
On Error GoTo Command1_Click_Err

    CloseAllOpenFrms

Command1_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command1_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command1_Click_Exit

End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' Command0_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Command0_Click()
On Error GoTo Command0_Click_Err

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2-popup", acNormal, "", "", , acWindowNormal


Command0_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command0_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command0_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

> Create another form `Form2-popup` and set Popup property to true
>   Add command button `Command1` with caption "Exit Form"

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Command1_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Command1_Click()
On Error GoTo Command1_Click_Err

    DoCmd.Close , ""


Command1_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command1_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command1_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. I put together the sample database. Then I opened Form 1, clicked the button to open the PopUp and then exited the database by Clicking the button on Form 1. The process still hangs in Task Manager.

Comment: One last thought - possibly a timing issue if you have a fast computer with caching. Let me modify my code above for the module

Comment: Mitch, thanks for all your help. Sleep didn't help. I guess I'll just continue manually closing these orphaned processes. We've spent enough time on this! Take care.

Comment: ouch. so weird. never seen anything like that